# MySQL gruop by when there is no aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **booking_details**.

```
id  |   tour_id |   tour_fee|   booking_id
1   |   1       |   200     |   1
2   |   2       |   350     |   1
3   |   1       |   200     |   2
4   |   2       |   350     |   3
```

**tour_id** refers to the **Tours** table and the **booking_id** refers **Bookings** table.
I want to get a report like this

tour_id 1 refers to New york tour
tour_id 2 refers to Paris tour

I need a generate a report something like this

```
tour name    |  total_income    |   number_of_bookings
New york tour|  400             |        2
Paris tour   |  700             |        2
```

Here basicaly tour name, total income from that tour and number of bookings for that tour.

What I have done upto now is this. But this gives me a syntax error. It seems I can't group by results.

```
SELECT booking_details.*,Tours.name as name, count(Tours.id) FROM booking_details
inner join Tours on
booking_details.tour_id = Tours.id group by Tours.name;
```

How do I achive this using MySQL?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html paying particular attention to the bit about functional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select non aggregated columns which are not part of your `GROUP BY` clause.

Change your query like following.

```
SELECT t.NAME           AS NAME, 
       Sum(bd.tour_fee) total_income, 
       Count(t.id)      number_of_bookings 
FROM   booking_details bd 
       INNER JOIN tours t 
               ON bd.tour_id = t.id 
GROUP  BY t.NAME;
```

Small suggestion, as a good practice you should use alias names for tables when joining.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all other columns in group by except aggregated fields

```
SELECT 
    booking_details.tour_id, 
    Tours.name AS name, 
    SUM(tourfee) AS total_income,
    COUNT(Tours.id) 
FROM 
    booking_details
INNER JOIN
    Tours ON booking_details.tour_id = Tours.id 
GROUP BY
    booking_details.tour_id, Tours.name
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used aggregation `count()` in your query and from your requirement, it shows you need aggregation. when you used aggregation you have to put selection column in group by also

```
   SELECT Tours.name as name,sum(tour_fee) income, count(Tours.id) 
   FROM booking_details
    inner join Tours on
    booking_details.tour_id = Tours.id group by Tours.name
```

As you used in selection `booking_details.*` which means every column of booking table but you have not put those column in group by so it thrown error